# Why does Vue3 log a warning when I use v-show in my component? (And can I safely ignore it?)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

Before I can get to my question, I going to try to provide some details.  I apologize for the length, but I think it's important to provide some background for what might be an unusual implementation as it might be related to my actual question.

I am working on migrating a website using Vue2 to Vue3.  The site in question hasn't been updated for some time, so I began by (first) backing up and (second) updating the environment (nodejs, npm, webpack) and the various installed packages (vue, vee-validate, etc).

This went as smoothly as you could hope for, but of course I ran into some problems with breaking-changes in Vue (and a few other packages).

My first real challenge was when I changed the older (Vue2) syntax:

```
var app = new Vue({...})
```

into the newer (Vue3) syntax:

```
createApp({...}).mount('#app');
```

Making this change seemed easy enough, but I quickly discovered when mounting the app, the innerHTML of the root element was always empty (nothing was created or mounted) - which was obviously wrong.  After some snooping, reading and trial-and-error I discovered this was due to the fact the site is using what the Vue documentation calls an **In-DOM Root Component Template**.  This simply means that instead of a single root component, the app is actually inferring the template from the content of the root element where the app is mounted.

An example of an In-DOM Root Component Template:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="some-layout-class another-class">
        <div class="use-neato-layout">
            <empty-component :some-id="42"></empty-component>
        </div>
        <div class="use-slick-layout">
            <blanco-component category="frumpy"></blanco-component>
            <empty-component :some-id="24"></empty-component>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

and the corresponding javascript

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'

import BlancoComponent from './BlancoComponent.vue';
import EmptyComponent from './EmptyComponent.vue';

createApp({
    components: {
        BlancoComponent,
        EmptyComponent
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

The important point here is to note that for this to work, you must change the import statement from the normal

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
```

into

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
```

Note: In-DOM Root Component Templates are clearly supported by Vue, and documented [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application#in-dom-root-component-template).  You can also read about the purpose of the vue.esm-bundler.js [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#note-on-in-browser-template-compilation).

I felt this was worth explaining for two reasons. First, using this In-DOM Root Component Template technique is an architectural constraint that I have to live with, and second, I am assuming I am doing this correctly (but I would gladly welcome any input if I have this wrong).

So at this point, I can render pages and their sub-components and start looking for errors, warnings or general weird behavior.  Which (finally) brings us to my question.

The first thing to jump out at me is this browser warning:

> [Vue warn]: withDirectives can only be used inside render functions.
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:179:13

After doing some isolation I was able to trace the warning to a simple v-show in a Vue component:

An example of the simplest Vue component ever:

```
<template>
    <div v-show="isMessageVisible">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isMessageVisible: true,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I remove the *v-show* from the **DIV** in the template, the warning disappears.  I can use *v-if* or *v-bind* and all kinds of groovy Vue3 stuff, but that simple *v-show* will throw a browser warning everywhere I use it.  Even more interesting, if the (reactive) isMessageVisible is changed in code, the warning will be re-issued (which kinda makes sense).

So what I want to know, is why is this warning generated and how can I fix it?  Or at least, can I safely ignore it?  I've scrounged around google but I am apparently the only? person experiencing this, which would normally indicate I am doing something wrong.  But if I am, I need a fresh set of eyes to point it out to me!

As always, thanks in advance for all input and assistance!